# Natural join returning zero rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, natural-join

```
Select book_id,title
from   Publisher
natural join Book natural join Category
where Publisher.name='thomas hardy' AND Category.name='computer science';
```

Comment: That's too bad? Did you have a question?

Comment: Why are you using `NATURAL JOIN`? What's the requirement here?

Comment: I need to get all the book titles for a specific publisher and a category so  search for both ids from their tables then join it with the books table to find the books, should i not use natural join ?

Comment: No. You should join on whatever fields makes the most sense to join them on. The Natural Join will join on the fields "Name" between Publisher and Category, and the Publishers "Name" probably has no relationship to the Category's "Name". Most likely you will want an INNER JOIN for your scenario.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just avoid `natural join`.  It looks for columns that are the same, and you might miss one somewhere.  For instance, almost all tables I create have a `CreatedAt` column.  And that would cause `NATURAL JOIN` to fail.

Instead, include a `USING` clause or explicit `ON`:

```
Select book_id,title
from Publisher join
     Book 
     using (Publisher_Id) join
     Category
     using (Category_Id)
where Publisher.name = 'thomas hardy' AND Category.name = 'computer science';
```

In fact, the mystery is solved.  The `NATURAL JOIN` will attempt to use `name` as a key.  And, I'm guessing no publishers have a name that exactly matches a category name.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a natural join it means that your tables will join on fields that share the same name. One of the fields in your Publisher table and your Category table is `Name` which means the natural join will join on these fields.

You then filter both fields by different criteria. After the two tables are joined, you can't have different values in the two fields.

It would be similar to writing:

```
Select foo FROM bar WHERE foo="something" and foo="Something Else"
```

It makes no sense. Natural joins are nice and all, but you are almost ALWAYS better off being explicit about your JOIN criteria, even if it feels a bit redundant. After all... comments in code are generally redundant, but only an asshat doesn't make them.